# How to parse JSON using volley library android

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I parsed JSON response using `Volley library` as done in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FzwBYPzCIHk). But I am getting an error. The error is:

> E/VOLLEY: ERROR

Can somebody help me, please? I don't know what the problem is.

**EDIT**: Added code

```
package com.example.hello.Project;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Activity1 extends Activity {

Button start;
TextView textView;
RequestQueue requestQueue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity1);

start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://example.com/abc.json",
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("abc");

                            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) { 

                                JSONObject student = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String a= student.getString("a");
                                String b= student.getString("b");
                                String c= student.getString("c");
                                String d= student.getString("d");

                                textView.append(a+" \n"+b+" \n"+c+" \n "+d+" \n");

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },

                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("VOLLEY","ERROR");
                    }
                }


        );

        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
});
}
}
```

This is the code.

Comment: Can you post the code that you've tried? Otherwise we can't really help you

Comment: Since it's a response error, it has nothing to do with JSON or it's correct format. Would you please change your error log to this: Log.e("VOLLEY", error.getMessage()); and add what the log says? That would help identify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't going to fix your problem, but it will tell you what's going wrong.

Change

```
new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("VOLLEY","ERROR");
                }
            }
```

to

```
new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
                }
            }
```

This way it will actually say what the error is, not just "ERROR".

The conclusion was that the sample JSON was invalid and therefore not being read in correctly.

Comment: That doesn't work. Do you have another idea to solve the problem?

Comment: It should have given you a different error than "E/VOLLEY: ERROR" - what did it say instead?

Comment: No, that is not the problem with your idea. When I write your idea, the error is red underlined. I can't start the app

Comment: OH Sorry I overlooked something. :)

Comment: You didn't overlook it - I just realized I missed the .toString() and added it in later ;)

Comment: ;)   Error:        E/VOLLEY: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 54 of...        Then there is the JSON-Data.

Comment: Thank you for the nice help. Can you look in the json-data what's wrong please?:) I haven't enough time yet, I would make it later.

Comment: Yep it's invalid JSON in the link you provided.

Comment: Check out [this json](https://data.oregon.gov/api/views/kafc-72dh/rows.json) and notice how all strings are in quotes. Throw the .json file you use in an online JSON validator and notice all of the errors. Get a better/correct json file to use and I'm willing to bet it'll work. (Maybe download that file, edit it to be correct, then point your app to the local file?)

Comment: Thank you very much for your really nice help.

Comment: No problem at all - if it works, just check my answer as correct as it has now been updated!

Comment: There's another problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41359559/how-to-parse-json-using-volley-library-android-error                        Can you help me again please? Thanks!

Comment: @android went to check it out, but it's gone -- get it all figured out?

Answer (score 0):

Further to @TJ_'s answer you also need to add comma's between each attribute.

You had (which is invalid):

```
{
  "buli1617sp": [
    {
      name: "Embolo"
      vereine: "Von Basel zu Schalke"
      geld: "29 Mio Euro"
      datum: "01.08.2016"
    },
    {
      name: "Coke"
      vereine: "Von Sevilla zu Schalke"
      geld: "4 Mio Euro"
      datum: "02.08.2016"
    },
    {
      name: "Bentaleb"
      vereine: "Von Basel zu Schalke"
      geld: "Leihe mit Kaufoption über 19 Mio Euro"
      datum: "03.08.2016"
    }
  ]
}
```

The correct JSON:

```
{
  "buli1617sp": [
    {
      "name": "Embolo",
      "vereine": "Von Basel zu Schalke",
      "geld": "29 Mio Euro",
      "datum": "01.08.2016"
    },
    {
      "name": "Coke",
      "vereine": "Von Sevilla zu Schalke",
      "geld": "4 Mio Euro",
      "datum": "02.08.2016"
    },
    {
      "name": "Bentaleb",
      "vereine": "Von Basel zu Schalke",
      "geld": "Leihe mit Kaufoption über 19 Mio Euro",
      "datum": "03.08.2016"
    }
  ]
}
```

When working with JSON I suggest using an online JSON parser such as [this](http://json.parser.online.fr/) to verify the JSON is correctly formatted.

Comment: Thanks for your help!